# pylab.imshow() command brings up blank figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm very new to working with Ipython and the Ipynotebook, but I need to for an upcoming class. Using the notebook, I imported pylab, created a data set using a matrix, and tried to display that data using the pylab.imshow(data) command. A figure is brought up in a separate window, but the figure is completely blank. On top of that, I can't close the figure window once it is open. I'm running Linux Mate 16 and Python 2.7. Here is the code that was run using the ipynotebook.

```
In [1]: import math

        import numpy as np

        import pylab as pl

        %pylab inline
#creating the matricies

In [2]: a = np.arrange(6)

        b = 10*a[:,np.newaxis]

        c = 2*a + b
#saving matrix as broadcasted.npz

In[3]: np.savez('broadcasted',c)

In[4]: a = np.load('broadcasted.npz')

       print a.files

In[5]: L = a['arr_0']

#attempting to display figures
In[6]: pl.figure()

       pl.imshow(L)
```

I don't get any errors, but the figure does not display properly. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: does `pl.imshow(rand(50, 50))` work?  My first guess is that `L` is not what you think it is.  You also should not import pylab, you should do `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Comment: Using pl.imshow(rand(50,50)) I ran into the same problem. Figure 1 showed up, but it was blank, and would not close until I closed the terminal. I've used import matplotlib.pyplot as plt before, and that worked just fine. The only reason I'm trying to use pylab in this way is because it is what the course instructor wants. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: Also thank you for formatting my question correctly.